# How to create a new list with items from an old list?

Tags: arrays, matlab, list, indexing

I have an array of ages ranging from 10 to 80 with no specific order (named 'Age'). I need to create a new list that includes only the indexes of the ages under 70 and above 16.

It is crucial that the **original indexes** of the ages 11-69 will be in the new list.

If anyone got an idea, try to share it with me, thanks everybody.

Comment: "It is crucial that the original indexes of the ages **11**-69 will be in the new list." - can you expand on this please. To me it directly contradicts your previous statement of " I need to create a new list that includes **only** the indexes of the ages under 70 and **above 16**.". Is this just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`find`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function to return the **indexes** that match a specific condition. In this case the condition is `age > 16 & age < 70` where `age` is the vector containing the values you are searching.

```
>> age = randi([10, 80], 10, 1)
age =

    21
    78
    77
    44
    66
    20
    39
    75
    66
    78

>> find(age > 16 & age < 70)
ans =

     1
     4
     5
     6
     7
     9
```

We can check this with

```
>> age(ans)
ans =

    21
    44
    66
    20
    39
    66
```

and we see that only values greater than 16 and less than 70 were returned by [`find`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).

Comment: Do you really need to use `find`? I think just `A = age(age > 16 & age < 70)`.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam He wants the **indexes** of the elements. So yes you have to use `find`. If he wanted the values your solution would be fine but he doesn't.